# How to define a continuous surjection from two sets

Tags: general-topology

How do I define a continuous surjection $f:D^n\times [0,1]\to (D^n\times\{0\})\cup (S^{n-1}\times [0,1])$ that is the left inverse to the inclusion function $i: (D^n\times\{0\})\cup (S^{n-1}\times [0,1])\to D^n\times [0,1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the desired retraction can be done by a simple geometric construction. Let $p = (0,2) \in \mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R$. For each $\xi \in D^n \times I$ let $L(\xi)$ denote the line connecting $p$ and $\xi$. Define

$r : D^n \times I \to B, r(\xi) =$ intersection point of $L(\xi)$ and $B = D^n \times \{0\} \cup S^{n-1} \times I$.

Drawing a picture is helpful. We shall formalize this. $L(\xi)$ is parameterized by $l_\xi(s) = p + s(\xi - p)$.  Now write $\xi = (x,t) \in D^n \times I$. Then$l_\xi(s) = (sx,2 + s(t-2))$. An easy calculation shows that $2 + s(t-2) \in [0,1]$ iff $\frac{1}{2-t} \le s \le \frac{2}{2-t}$.

1. $L(\xi)$ intersects $\mathbb R^n \times \{0\}$ for $2 + s(t-2) = 0$, i.e. for $s = \frac{2}{2-t}$. We have $\frac{2}{2-t}x \in D^n$ for $\lVert x \rVert \le \frac{2-t}{2}$, thus we get
   $$r(x,t) = (\frac{2}{2-t}x,0)$$
   for $\lVert x \rVert \le \frac{2-t}{2}$.
2. $L(\xi)$ intersects $S^{n-1} \times I$ when $\lVert sx \rVert = 1$, i.e. $ s  = \pm \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}$, and $\frac{1}{2-t} \le s \le \frac{2}{2-t}$. Note that for $x = 0$ we do not get an intersection. We conlude that we must have $s  = \frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}$ and $\frac{2-t}{2} \le \lVert x \rVert \le 2-t$. Since $2-t \ge 1$, we get
   $$r(x,t) = (\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert},2+\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}(t-2))$$
   for $\lVert x \rVert \ge \frac{2-t}{2}$.

Summarizing our geometric construction gives us the formula
$$r(x,t) = \begin{cases} (\frac{2}{2-t}x,0) & \lVert x \rVert \le \frac{2-t}{2} \\ (\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert},2+\frac{1}{\lVert x \rVert}(t-2)) & \lVert x \rVert \ge \frac{2-t}{2} \end{cases}$$
For $\lVert x \rVert = \frac{2-t}{2}$ both lines give the same value $(\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert},0)$. The map $r$ is clearly continuous and we have $r(\xi) = \xi$ for $\xi \in B$.